# Create cookie for subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

We have multiple subdomains: `es.mysite.com`, `pt.mysite.com`, `www.mysite.com` depending upon the language needed.

When we do the following, it creates a `cookie` per subdomain, but we want to create a cookie that can be used for all our subdomains.

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'en', strtotime('+7 day'), '/')
```

**How would i create a `cookie` using `php7` such that the domain is set to `.mysite.com` for the `cookie's` domain value?**

Current result:

1. if i navigate to `es.mysite.com`, `cookie` is create with `domain = es.mysite.com`
2. if i navigate to `pt.mysite.com`, `cookie` is create with `domain = pt.mysite.com`

Desired Output:

1. if i navigate to `es.mysite.com`, `cookie` is create with `domain = .mysite.com`
2. if i navigate to `pt.mysite.com`, `cookie` is create with `domain = .mysite.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the main domain to the end like this:

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'en', strtotime('+7 day'), '/', 'mysite.com');
```

Comment: I had to pass the `domain` as a string and it worked, thanks. `setcookie('mycookie', 'en', strtotime('+7 day'), '/', 'mysite.com');`